# Aggregating result of many to many join of points closest to line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, spatial-join, proximity, many-to-many

I have a layer of points and a second layer of lines. The goal is to know for each line, how many and which points (by `"ID"`) are closest to that line, to then export this information for further analysis.

[image: Points and lines.]

I used a Spatial join to associate each point with the nearest line (i.e. my points now have the road information in their attribute table), but now fail to understand how I can use this to add the point `"ID"`s to the lines. QGIS' regular join operation is only 1->1 and therefore gives me only one point `"ID"`, even though there are obviously multiple points. How can I store the `"ID"`s of all points as an attribute in the matching line?

I googled quite a bit but seem to have troubles to find the right terms to describe what I want to do. I also tried using the relations functionality in QGIS but not with satisfying results. Maybe the relations functionality is not suitable for exports.

Comment: There is only ever going to be 1 point closest to each line. It sounds like what you want is actually the inverse of what you describe. Would it not be better to determine which line is closest to each point?

Comment: As you now have the line ID for each point you could work your analysis on the point layer (for exemple selecting all point with the same line ID give you the list and total number of points related to this line...)

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Giving you only one point id is sensible. Otherwise, join operation would generate hundreds/thousands of columns in the line layer for each near point.

One solution would be to add all near point ids to a single string typed field using the following PyQGIS script.

```py
point_layer_name = "Point_Layer"
line_layer_name = "Line_Layer"

# reference of layers
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(point_layer_name)[0]
line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(line_layer_name)[0]

# check if field storing ids exists. if not add a new field
if line_layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("POINT_IDS") == -1:
    line_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("POINT_IDS", QVariant.String, len=100)])
    line_layer.updateFields()


field_idx = line_layer.fields().indexOf('POINT_IDS')
with edit(line_layer):

    # reset POINT_IDS values
    for feature in line_layer.getFeatures():
       line_layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), field_idx, '')

    # iterate over points
    for point in point_layer.getFeatures():
        
        distances = {line.id(): point.geometry().distance(line.geometry()) 
                                for line in line_layer.getFeatures()}
        
        # find the nearest line id
        nearest_line_id = min(distances, key=distances.get)
        # get the line by id
        line = line_layer.getFeature(nearest_line_id)    
        # append the point id to the line's POINT_IDS 
        line["POINT_IDS"] += str(point.id()) + " " # you can use comma instead of space
        
        line_layer.updateFeature(line)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

A solution using QGIS expressions:

1. Go to the point layer to create an attribute containing the id of the closest line using this expression

   ```
    array_first (
        overlay_nearest (
            'line', 
            line_id
        )
    )
   ```
2. On the line layer, create a new attribute concatenating the id of the points that are closest to the current feature:

```
    with_variable (
        'lineid',
        $id,
        aggregate (
            'point',
            'concatenate',
            to_string(pointid),
            filter:=closest_line=@lineid,
            concatenator:=','
        )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution utilizes a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)  through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are two layers *'random_points_test'* (10 features) and *'lines_test'* (three features), see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query (it includes [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/), [`ST_Within()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html), and [`ST_Buffer()`](https://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html)), it is possible *to store the `"ID"`s of all points as an attribute in the matching line*.

```sql
SELECT
    lines.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(poi."id") AS "poi_ids"
FROM
    "lines_test" AS lines
LEFT JOIN
    "random_points_test" AS poi
WHERE
    st_within(poi.geometry, st_buffer(lines.geometry, 100000))
GROUP BY
    lines."id"
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: result1]

*Note:* Value of 100000 in the `st_buffer()` corresponds to the maximum distance from a line feature to points.

To get how many points are closest to that line, add the following string  `COUNT(*) AS "poi_n"` into the query:

```sql
SELECT
    lines.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(poi."id") AS "poi_ids",
    COUNT(*) AS "poi_n"
FROM
    "lines_test" AS lines
LEFT JOIN
    "random_points_test" AS poi
WHERE
    st_within(poi.geometry, st_buffer(lines.geometry, 100000))
GROUP BY
    lines."id"
```

So, now the output will look like

[image: result2]

---

Another similar query (it includes [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/), [`ST_ShortestLine()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ShortestLine.html), and [`ST_Length()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html)):

```sql
SELECT
    lines.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(poi."id") AS "poi_ids"
FROM
    "lines_test" AS lines
LEFT JOIN
    "random_points_test" AS poi
WHERE
    ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(poi.geometry, lines.geometry)) < 100000
GROUP BY
    lines."id"
```